# How to get the configuration of field having multiple columns and values in magento 2

Tags: magento2

How to get the values separately for the fields of the following type:

[image]

I am using

```
$objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('ced_wallet/requestwallet/percentage');
```

in Block/Adminhtml/Blockname/Grid/Renderer/Approve.php

Please suggest any solution to get these type of configurations.

Comment: is this a product level attribute?

Comment: No, custom module configurations

Comment: store configuration?

Comment: yes, we added in our module system.xml.

Comment: We need to get this values when the admin click on approve in the grid. The i have to apply the percentage based on the price ranges...how??? See the screenshot you can understand.

Comment: $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORES;

echo $this->scopeConfig->getValue("example_section/general/field_data", $storeScope);

Comment: By using that i will get the result like this:
{"_1549454146216_216":{"start_range":"1000","end_range":"10000","mode":"0.05"},"_1549454186064_64":{"start_range":"10000","end_range":"25000","mode":"0.1"},"_1549454206185_185":{"start_range":"25000","end_range":"50000","mode":"0.5"}}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89381/discussion-between-kiran-kumar-and-hiren-kadivar).

Comment: can we add a dropdown in this type of configuration.
For Example we are using From and To columns. I need Type dropdown instead of To column.

Comment: When i tried to add type i'm getting    ReferenceError: type is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find a solution after several code trials. Please check the below example:

```
$config = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('section/group/field');
    $values = (array)json_decode($config, true);
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($values as $value) {
      $start = $value['start_range'];
      $end = $value['end_range'];
      $percent = $value['mode'];
    }
```